# How insert item on top table

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

How insert item on top table in PostgreSQL? That it is possible? In the table I have only two fields as text. First is primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE news_table (
    title text not null primary key,
    url text not null    
);
```

I need a simple query for the program in java.

OK, this is my code:

```
get("/getnews", (request, response) -> {
    List<News> getNews = newsService.getNews();
    List<News> getAllNews = newsService.getAllNews();
    try (Connection connection = DB.sql2o.open()) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO news_table(title, url) VALUES (:title, :url)";
        for (News news : getNews) {
            if (!getAllNews.contains(news)) {
                connection.createQuery(sql, true)
                        .addParameter("title", news.getTitle())
                        .addParameter("url", news.getUrl())
                        .executeUpdate()
                        .getKey();
            }

        }
    }
    return newsService.getNews();
}, json());
```

The problem is that as it calls getnews method for the second time this new news adds at the end of the table, and there is no extant hronologi news. How this resolve? I use Sql2o + sparkjava.

Probably already I know. I need to reverse the List  getnews before I will must contains object getnews and getallnews?

Comment: `insert into new_table (title, url) values ('The Title', 'The URL');`

Comment: There is no such thing as "the top of a table"

Comment: To learn how to use a database with Java, please see the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no start or end in a table. If you want to sort your data, just use an ORDER BY in your SELECT statements. Without ORDER BY, there is no order.

Answer (score 1):

Relational theory, the mathematical foundation of relational databases, lays down certain conditions that relations (represented in real databases as tables) must obey. One of them is that they have no ordering (*i.e.*, the rows will neither be stored nor retrieved in any particular order, since they are treated as a mathematical set). It's therefore completely under the control of the RDBMS where a new row is entered into a table.

Hence there is no way to ensure a particular ordering of the data without using an `ORDER BY` clause when you retrieve the data.